# Осваиваю методы в Java. Метод должен возвращать факториал числа. Подскажите, почему ругается компилятор?

Tags: java, методы, факториал

```
public class ExMy01MethodFactorialQuestion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    int f = getFctrl(a);
    System.out.println(f);
}

public static int getFctrl(int g) {
    int fctrl = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= g; i++) {
        fctrl = fctrl * i;
        return fctrl;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: потому что `i++` никогда не выполнится

Comment: Игорь, а в чем ошибка?

Comment: Найдите отличие между Вашим и моим кодом.

Comment: В вопрос нужно включить сообщение об ошибке, которую выдает компилятор, и указать, на какой строке она возникает. Также попробуйте сократить код до минимального примера на котором ошибка воспроизводится.

Comment: 1)Прочитайте [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), как задать хороший вопрос
2)Если ответ помог вам, нажмите на стрелочку рядом с ним
3)Если ответ решил вашу проблему, то примите его, нажав галочку рядом с ним

Comment: @Igor, простите, не заметил код, я новичок тут ))

Comment: @Anton238, спасибо за рекомендацию, обязательно разберусь ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*А классно было бы, если бы Вы включили в вопрос сообщение компилятора?*

---

Ваш `return` выходит из функции на первой итерации. Это раз. Кроме того,  компилятор считает, что существуют значения `g`, при которых функция вообще ничего не возвращает. Компиляторы этого не любят. Это два.

```
public static int getFctrl(int g) {
    int fctrl = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= g; i++) {
        fctrl = fctrl * i;
    }
    return fctrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно кстати использовать вместо Integer для подсчета факториала - BigInteger. Тогда уже после 13! все будет верно выводиться. Пример можно [тут](https://fox-code.ru/a/vychislenie-faktoriala-kotlin/) посмотреть

Comment: мало того, что **вместо** ответа вы приводите ссылку (не перенеся её основное содержимое в ответ), так ещё и по ссылке речь идёт о **другом** языке программирования.